# CSV.writer each set entry on a new line

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

**Environment:** Python 3.7 on Windows
**Goal:** Write out a set to a .csv file, with each set entry on a new line.
**Problem:** Each set entry is not on a new line... when I open the CSV file in Excel, every set entry is in a separate column, rather than a separate row.
**Question:** What do I need to do to get each set entry written on a new line?

```
import csv
test_set = {'http://www.apple.com', 'http://www.amazon.com', 'http://www.microsoft.com', 'https://www.ibm.com'}
with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows([test_set])
    f.close()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You passed `writer.writerows()` a list with a single element, and so it wrote a single row.

You need to convert your set to a series of rows; each row a list with the row contents. You could use a generator expression to produce the rows:

```
writer.writerows([value] for value in test_set)
```

However, you are not really producing a CSV here. With a single column, you may as well just write the set contents directly to a file with newlines in between. The `print()` function can be co-opted for this task:

```
with open('output.csv', 'w') as f:
    print(*test_set, sep='\n', file=f)
```